# Sitecore 8.2 versioning not working in final layout

Tags: presentation

I have a Sitecore 8.2 build which is behaving quite opposite way to what sitecore defines versioning to be.
When I make a second version for an item and make changes to the final layout, it applies the changes to all versions of that item.

Example. I added a new component on to the final layout of version 2 and the component appears in version 1 also.

Is this versioning enabled by default in 8.2 or should me manually change some config to enable it. Please help.

Comment: How are you adding the new component?

Comment: I tried adding on the experience editor and from presentation>details.
It's adding the component on all versions in both cases.

Comment: check __Final Renderings filed in template "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Layout" default it's versioned and not shared. if it's checked in any of this option then it might be the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @GobinathSaminathan . It seems to have fixed the issue. :)

Comment: that's great.. posted the same below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default **__Final Renderings** is versioned and not shared, so make sure **__Final Renderings** filed in template "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Layout" as below.

[image]